# Tomcat: what happens when a HTTP Multipart request gets interrupted?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, file-upload

From my understanding of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242672/where-do-file-upload-streams-get-the-content-from), when the Tomcat server receives a HTTP Multipart request, the servlet will only be invoked after the transfer of all the parts is completed.

What happens if the transfer gets interrupted in the middle? (For example if the network connection of the client drops while uploading a 1Gb file?) When will the servlet be invoked in this case?

To be specific, I can see inside my servlet some not-properly closed `java.io.InputStream` (from an interrupted transfer probably), but I would expect that the server would reject the Multipart as incomplete even before invoking the servlet? How to explain theses not-properly closed files? The HTTP protocol has some control mechanisms to prevent incomplete requests.    (I'm using `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem` from [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload))

My question might not be specific to Java/Tomcat.

Comment: The server's read timeout will kick in and the connection will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that Tomcat in all those years forgot to close Multipart streams, although not impossible considering the huge amount of bugs. But my guess is that this is somewhere else in your application code.

In general if the client fails to properly upload the multipart stream this is an error on the protocol level and has nothing to do with your application, so the server handles it. This is about the same as if someone would call a web address but only the first half is entered. This is all handled by the server, because the answer can only be to terminate the connection at that point.